# Can not parse large file with boost spirit

Tags: boost, locale, boost-spirit

I have a large file. It's code page is CP1251. I want to parse it with boost spirit. And I parse it successfully while the parser meets non-standard characters.
The boost documentation says:

> Wide-character versions of the memory-mapped file Devices may be defined as follows, using the template code_converter:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/code_converter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

typedef code_converter<mapped_file_source>  wmapped_file_source;
typedef code_converter<mapped_file_sink>    wmapped_file_sink;
```

But should I use it?
I my code I shouldn't have a sink. I suppose: my parser uses iterator from the source, code_converter converts them using code page I gave him, and send the translated chars to parser and it parses the file.

So, this is part of my code which doesn't work:

```
typedef boost::iostreams::code_converter<boost::iostreams::mapped_file>      wmapped_file_source;  
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale lru = gen("ru_RU.CP1251");
wmapped_file_source mmap;
mmap.imbue(lru);
mmap.open(current_task.filename);

RhAst::RhFile rh_file(this);
bool res = phrase_parse(mmap->begin(), mmap->end(), parser, space - eol, rh_file);
```

I tried to create my own locale object:

```
    class LocaleRus : public std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>
{
public:
    explicit LocaleRus(size_t r = 0) : std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> ( r )
    {
    }

protected:
    result do_in ( state_type&, const char* from, const char* from_end, const char*& from_next, char* to, char*, char*& to_next ) const
    {
        const int size = from_end - from;
        //::OemToCharBuff ( from, to, size );

        from_next = from + size;
        to_next = to + size ;

        return ok;
    }

    result do_out ( state_type&, const char* from, const char* from_end, const char*& from_next, char* to, char*, char*& to_next ) const
    {
        const int size = from_end - from;
        //::CharToOemBuff ( from, to, size );

        from_next = from + size;
        to_next = to + size ;

        return ok;
    }

    result do_unshift ( state_type&, char*, char*, char*& ) const { return ok; }
    int do_encoding () const throw () { return 1; }
    bool do_always_noconv () const throw () { return false; }

    int do_length ( state_type& state, const char* from, const char* from_end, size_t max ) const
    {
        return std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::do_length ( state, from, from_end, max );
    }

    int do_max_length () const throw ()
    {
        return std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::do_max_length ();
    }
};
```

and use it in code:

```
std::locale lru(std::locale(), new LocaleRus());
```

But its methods don't call.
So, I didn't mind that it's too hard to read a memory mapped file with a non-standard code page. What do I do incorrectly?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you are using default character parsers which are from `ascii` namespace and they are designed to accept only ascii characters. You can use parsers from `boost::spirit::standard` (like `boost::spirit::standard::char_`) to work with single-byte encodings or `boost::spirit::standard_wide` to work with wide-characters and `boost::spirit::unicode` to work with unicode characters.

Comment: The code_converter should convert the code page into ascii or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should use it ¹, definitely.

What you're looking for is Spirit's stream-iterators. It has some predefined (`boost::spirit::istream_iterator`), but obviously you need custom types because of the custom stream.

What `boost::spirit::istream_iterator` does is *wrap* a regular iterator in the [Multipass Iterator Adapter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/multi_pass.html). Basically what it does is remove the forward-only-and-single-use limitations of [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator).

It does so by keeping a buffer for backtracking.

I think you should be able to use something similar to:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale lru = gen("ru_RU.CP1251");

typedef boost::iostreams::code_converter<boost::iostreams::mapped_file>      wmapped_file_source;  
wmapped_file_source mmap;
mmap.imbue(lru);
mmap.open(current_task.filename);

RhAst::RhFile rh_file(this);

boost::iostreams::stream<wmapped_file_source> map_source(mmap);

typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> base_iterator_type;

spirit::multi_pass<base_iterator_type>
    first = spirit::make_default_multi_pass(base_iterator_type(map_source)),
    last  = spirit::make_default_multi_pass(base_iterator_type());

bool res = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, qi::blank, rh_file);
```

Notes:

1. I typed this in the browser, no time to check it yet
2. You could use `boost::iostreams::stream_buf` instead - perhaps being more efficient(?)
3. `qi::space - qi::eol` is `qi::blank`, so likely using `boost::spirit::qi::blank_type` as the skipper is more efficient
4. BEWARE: depending on how your grammar is structured you might run into bad multi-pass edge cases. You may want to be explicit about when to flush (expectation points do this automatically), see e.g.

   - [Boost spirit memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504267/boost-spirit-memory-leak/40515812#40515812)
   - [How to incrementally parse (and act on) a large file with Boost.Spirit.Qi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748596/how-to-incrementally-parse-and-act-on-a-large-file-with-boost-spirit-qi/41753143#41753143)
   - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97838/discussion-between-loloof64-and-sehe
   - And this useful directive https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/primitive/flush_multi_pass.html

---

¹ assuming the conversions do what you need them to do

Comment: IIUC OP has the problem that `char_` fails on non-ascii characters (`boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii::ischar(0xE0)` will return false).

Comment: Possibly. I don't see any parser expression, so it's hard to tell

Comment: I forgot to say, I use spirit x3, but prbably it doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: @Nikita Kniazev, if I translate the input file into local 8-bit code page before the parsing, I parse it successfully. But I cannot do it because it's very large and the maximum size is undefined. I think the code_converter should do the work of translating on-the-fly and I can use the parser expressions without any changes (char_ or wchar_).

Comment: @sehe, why do I need the buffer backtracking?

Comment: "if I translate the input file into local 8-bit code page before the parsing" - in your question you said it's already: "I have a large file. It's code page is CP1251." You'd better to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @denn You need it in order to run a PEG parser because - by nature - it must be able to backtrack, which isn't possible on `InputIterator` (requires at least `ForwardIterator`). The linked docs for `multi_pass` should explain in much more detail